# Need Eclipse tip -how to build quickly/automatically the main Android project when working on a library project

Tags: android, eclipse

I have 2 projects as described in this [http://developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html) page.
I'm using Eclipse 3.5.2

The Library project has all the sources and most resources while the main project is just a shell (a few params and images).

So in essence, I mostly make changes in the library project.

Currently each time I want to run the app in the emulator, I have to

- build the library (ctrl + b)
- refresh the main project (right-click on project => F5)
- (sometimes) clean the main project (Project -> Clean -> ok)
- run the main project (ctrl + f11)

This is a long/painful process that involves lots of clicks and mouse manipulation so I'm just wondering if there is some kind of setting I missed that would allow me with a shortcut (macro?) to run the main project directly from the library.

I hope the question makes sense and I'm happy to provide my projects properties if needed.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I found that I can tick "Buid automatically" and "Refresh automatically" under Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace, but the refresh takes between 10-20 seconds which means it's still faster to click on the main Procject and hit F5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the answers from *dziobas* actually put me on the right track, here is how I solved my issue:

- as suggested by *dzioba* I removed and re-added the library
- I ticked *Buid automatically* and *Refresh automatically* under Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace

And most importantly:

- I now edit my Library sources files not from within the library project but from within the main project. That way hitting F11 do run the main project (as it's the current one) and not the library

Sorry I had to answer my own question but I thought it might help somebody else one day!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify dependencies in the project settings. (I'm not at my Eclipse computer right now, so I can't look it up right now - I can edit the answer tonight if you can't find it).

If you do that, Eclipse will automatically build the dependencies when you build the main project.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by dependencies, but the main project has the library projet under `Project References`, under `Java Build Path - Source`, under `Java Build Path - Projects` and it's 3rd after `/src` and `/gen` under `Java Build Path - Order and Export`

Answer (score 0):

It should work seamless. Create main Android Project, in project properties>Android>Library set your Android Library Project.

edited:
If still not works, remove library from properties, apply changes and add it again.

See Eclipse shortcuts to run:

http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/Keyboard_shortcuts_(3.0).pdf

Comment: That's what I've done. The library project is the Library list in `Properties - Android`. Yet I have to do all the process described

Comment: Sometimes that helps: remove library from properties, apply changes and add it again.

Comment: OK that helped! It seems I had some wrong references/dependencies.
Now with the options "Buid automatically" and "Refresh automatically" ticked it's all instantaneous. 
But after editing the project library, I still need to select manually the main project to run it or Eclipse tells me (rightly) "Android projects cannot be launched"...

Comment: To relaunch last is F9 or F11, look into Eclipse shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but actually with Eclipse 3.5, F11 runs the current project, not the last project launched. If I'm editing the Library source files then the current project is the Library project which can't be launched...